# how do I get event.target to return a specific target element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react application I have this button which acts like state switcher this button has an id attribute/prop and this button wraps a font-awesome icon.

```
<button id={feedId}>
   <i className={isStatus === 'Y' ? 'fa fa-unlock' : 'fa fa-lock'} /> 
   {isStatus === 'Y' ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}
</button>
```

Now depending upon where you click on the button the `event.target` would return the entire button with id or just the icon that's `<i>` tag how do I make sure that entire button gets return as part of event.target instead of just `<i>`

Comment: What are you using `event.target` for?

Comment: Why, what do you ultimately want to do? Sounds like [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/252139).

Comment: Set up the event handler on the button and then check `event.target` to see if it is the button or not. Only proceed when it is the button. Because of bubbling, the button will receive the event all the time.

Comment: @ Hunter McMillen To get the id there are several such buttons in the application. id plays important part as it is use to make api calls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `currentTarget`

```js
function test(e) {
  console.log('Target ', e.target);
  console.log('Current Target ', e.currentTarget)
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button id="test" onclick="test(event)">
       <i class="fa fa-quora" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       Text
    </button>
```